# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() in for loop

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, valueerror

So I'm trying to make my first A.I project a Language Translation program using  **Natural Language Processing**
and there seems to be an error and I don't know how to solve it.

```
preds = model.predict(testX.reshape((testX.shape[0],testX.shape[1])))
```

These predictions are sequences of integers. We need to convert these integers to their corresponding words. So I defined a function to do this:

```
def get_word(n, tokenizer):
      for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
          if index == n:
              return word
      return None
```

Then this code will Convert predictions into text.

```
#convert predictions into text (english)
preds_text = []
for i in preds:
       temp = []
       for j in range(len(i)):
            t = get_word(i[j], eng_tokenizer)
            if j > 0:
                if (t == get_word(i[j-1], eng_tokenizer)) or (t == None):
                     temp.append('')
                else:
                     temp.append(t)
            else:
                   if(t == None):
                          temp.append('')
                   else:
                          temp.append(t) 

       preds_text.append(' '.join(temp))
```

Here is the error,

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\ai\colab (1).ipynb Cell 22' in <cell line: 2>()
      3 temp = []
      4 for j in range(len(i)):
----> 5      t = get_word(i[j], eng_tokenizer)
      6      if j > 0:
      7          if (t == get_word(i[j-1], eng_tokenizer)) or (t == None):
```

And here is the source code where you can find everything you need.
[Source Code](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/01/neural-machine-translation-keras/)

Comment: what does the function `get_word` return ? ... and in which line of the code the ValueError is found ?

Comment: Hi Bhushan, welcome to Stack Overflow! In your code, it's good to provide us more info on what is the variable `preds` and the function `get_word`. This `ValueError` can be caused by many situations.

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew

Comment: Do you want to recheck your texts input? If you are following the code exactly according to the website, it should work.